# django form won't populate decimal value with instance

Tags: python, django

I have the following form:

```
class SearchDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price_min = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, required=False)
    price_max = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, required=False)
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), required=False)
    max_distance = forms.CharField(required=False)
    sort = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SORT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Buy
        fields = (
                  'item',
                  'max_distance',
                  'price_min',
                  'price_max'
                  )
```

The view that implements this form looks like:

```
def market_view(request):

    max_distance = request.GET.get('max_distance',None)
    price_min_str = request.GET.get('price_min',None)
    price_max_str = request.GET.get('price_max',None)
    price_min = Decimal(price_min_str)
    price_max = Decimal(price_max_str)
    item = request.GET.get('item',None)

    buy = Buy()
    buy.price_min = Decimal('10.10')
    buy.price_max = Decimal('10.10')
    buy.item = Item.objects.get(pk=item)

    buy_items = Buy.objects.filter(price__lte=price_max,price__gte=price_min).order_by('item')

    form = SearchDetailForm(instance=buy)

    context = {
        'items':buy_items,
        'form':form,

    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I set the form instance to `buy` so that the last searched values would remain on the page.  The `item` attribute remains, but the `price_min` and `price_max` do not.  What can I have them do to populate in the form instance?

Comment: Not the problem, but I don't understand why you're getting distance/price etc from `request.GET` and converting it manually, rather than passing the whole thing to the form and getting it automatically converted via `form.cleaned_data`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was doing this because I was http-getting, rather than posting to have the values remain in the form.  I guess your saying I could pass the data via cleaned_data even with a get?

Comment: Sure, you can do `SearchDetailForm(request.GET)` just as well as with `request.POST`; they're both querydicts.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the bonus tip.  Always good to hear from the obi wan kenobi of django!